# Low bounce rate with extremely low average session duration in GA

Tags: google-analytics

I have a site that GA is hooked up to, and it has a low bounce rate, around 1%, but it also has an extremely low average session time, at around 0:02.

Is this, de facto, an extremely high bounce rate that's being missed because session times are not, in fact, exactly zero?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User or https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It seems, that you send an additional PV or Event, that "destroys" the Bounce Rate. It would be helpfull if you could provide a url.